# Как применить скрипт ко всем постам? (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Всем привет!
Есть сайт на вордпресс, каталог сделал через посты в админке.
Идея в том, что карточки должны раскрываться по нажатию (изначальный вариант через css по наведению неудобен)
Долго мучался, пытался заставить это оживить, но никакой реакции на скрипт не было. Его написание я отложил, решил простейшим проверить, работает оно или нет. В результате скрипт применяется только на первую позицию, на остальные не желает. Если поставить скрипт перед reset postdata то срабатывает 7 раз (по количеству постов) при клике на первую позицию, на остальные не реагирует.
Вопроса два:

- как заставить его применяться к каждой карточке по отдельности?
- как должен выглядеть скрипт, заставляющий раскрываться карточку и показывать текст? просто прописать там другой style или все сложнее? Прикрепил закрытую и раскрытую карточку
  Спасибо

  ```
    <div class="products__item" id="item">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(380, 250), array('class'=> "products__item-img")); ?>
        <h4 class="products__item-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <div class="products__item-box">
            <p class="products__item-text"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php }} wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <script>
      var myLink = document.getElementById("item");
      function doSomething() {
      alert("Вы нажали на div-ссылку!");
      }
      myLink.addEventListener("click", doSomething);
    </script>
  ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: `В результате скрипт применяется только на первую позицию, на остальные не желает` - всё правильно, у Вас повторяется id, а он должен быть уникальным для каждого блока. В скрипте лучше использовать не идентификатор, а какой-то общий класс и this.